# Get UUID of an iOS device?

Tags: ios, uuid

I have developed an app for my company and now it is the test phase. I am away from them (living in another city) and want to add my coworkers UUID in my developer profile to see the app. But how to find UUID of other iOS devices remotely? Is there any option in Settings that show them their UUID?

Comment: The owner of the device needs to get it the UDID and sent it to you.

Comment: How the owner of device find the UUID of his iOS device?

Comment: See the linked duplicate at the top of your question.

Comment: Yes, thanks! how to close my question rmaddy?

Comment: It's already closed.